# Does imperative + semicolon + declarative necessitate a causal relationship?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, conjunctions, history

For instance, take the sentence "Go wash the windows; I like green bears." Given that the two clauses must be closely related because they are joined by a semicolon, is there any other way to interpret this sentence besides it being a command to wash the windows *because* the speaker likes green bears? Alternatively, if the order is reversed ("I like green bears; go wash the windows") is there any other way to interpret the sentence besides "I like the green bears, *so* go wash the windows"? I'm asking this question as it pertains to a 19th century British poem, so I'd like to know if the usage in this particular case is any different for that time/location.

This would be different from instances where a semicolon could have multiple specific meanings, like "Go wash the windows; don't break the ladder" (the semicolon could be replaced by "and" or "but") or "Roses are red; violets are blue" (ditto). (Are there other interpretations for those sentences as well?)

Comment: Good question. Can you give us a link to the poem, please? I cannot think of any instance where a semicolon connecting a preceding imperative with a following declarative would *not* imply "because," but if the poem calls it into question for you, let's have a look at it.

Comment: I'm guessing Keats' *Ode to a Green Bear*.

Comment: Ha, actually it's [An Invite to Eternity](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/an-invite-to-eternity/) by John Clare. Sorry I forgot to include it earlier, it must have slipped my mind...

Answer (score 3):

A semi-colon connecting a declarative and an imperative can indicate a non-causal association.  For example, "Red sky at morning; sailors take warning."  The red-sky in the morning doesn't cause bad weather or vice versa.  The red-sky and the forthcoming bad weather are both effects of a common cause: the pressure involved (high or low).

Comment: "Sailors take warning" can be parsed as declarative rather than imperative, and its contrastive partner "Sailors delight" seems *more* likely declarative than imperative, if "delight" is even a verb at all. ("Sailor's delight" is an eminently possible alternative reading.) In any case, we do not there have the pattern imperative+semicolon+declarative, with the imperative *preceding* the semicolon.

Comment: Yes, "sailors take warning" can be viewed as a declarative -- noticing a fact about sailors. "Sailors take warning" can be viewed as an imperative: "Sailors should take warning" or "Sailors! "Take warning."   As to your second point requiring the imperative first.  You gave two examples. With the imperative first, the semi-colon functioned as "because". With the imperative second, the semi-colon functioned as "so".  My example responded to the "so" case.  To reply to your first case, simply reverse the admonition:  "Sailors take warning; red sky at morning."

Comment: On re-reading your post, the title (does this necessitate a causal relationship) is completely separate from everything in your post (the semi-colon indicates either 'because' or 'so'.  Yes, 'because' and 'so' can be used in expressing causal relationships, but that is not a requirement.